# c++: how to write a destructor for a vector combined with a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, destructor

I need to write a destructor for an exercise of school. I already tried to write the destructor for class A, is this the right or the wrong way?

[Exercise on paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6gpk.jpg)

The exercise says the destructor needs to start like:

```
A *pa = .......;
delete pa;
```

The code of the 4 classes:

```
Class A
{
  private:
    vector <B*> b;
    vector <C*> c;
  public:
    ~A();
}

Class B
{
  private:
    vector <D*> d;
  public:
    ~B();
}

Class C
{
  private:
    vector <D*> d;
  public:
    ~C();
}

Class D
{
  private:
    vector <A*> a;
  public:
    ~D();
}
```

I've already tried to write the destructor for class `A`,
is this the correct way?

```
~A()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
  {
     B* pa = b[i];
     delete pa;
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < c.size(); i++)
  {
    C* pa = c[i];
    delete pa;
  }
```

Comment: I can see `new` in your class so you do not need `delete`. It is better to use smart pointer instead.

Comment: I assume that these pointers were allocated using `new`?

Comment: You do not have `constructor` as well!

Comment: Didn't you already post this exact question a couple of hours ago? Please don't repost the exact same question multiple times, *edit the existing* question instead. That will also push your question up on the question list on the front page.

Comment: It will cause unknown result if you delete pointers that are not allocated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are not sure that the pointers in the two `vector`s  in class `A` are all **not** `NULL`, then you can do the following:

```
~A()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
    delete b[i];
  b.clear(); // Making sure you do not access to deleted pointers

  for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
    delete c[i];
  c.clear();  // Making sure you do not access to deleted pointers
}
```

We also clear the vectors, in order to be sure not to access to deleted pointes. Alternatively, if you still need the vectors' sizes, you can just set
`b[i] = nullptr` and `c[i] = nullptr` in the two loops, without clearing the vectors.

Comment: `nullptr` is available in c++11?

Comment: _The vectors are destroyed immediately after the destructor body ends, so clearing has no advantage except to prevent accidential access later within the destructor._ For this exact reason I clear them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I understand what you mean, but what to do in the case of class B and C? In the deconstructor of these I need to delete A. Would that not give a problem? If B already deleted A, C couldn't delete A?

Comment: @Michael fair enough, but in my opinion, the destructor is so simple that I can see at a glance that the vectors are not accessed after their pointers have been deleted. And that's the case for any destructor of a well designed class. I see you removed the false statements, so I removed my down vote.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out, @user2079303.
Anyway, the after-deletion accesses are strictly dependent on the future code development. So, just in case, in this way I'm making sure nothing bad happens. You are probably right anyway, since this looks as a simple exercise on costructor/destructors.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If `A` *owns* the pointers in the vectors and is therefore responsible for the destruction of the pointed objects and the objects were created using `new`, then yes the destructor does appear to be correct.

If the pointed objects were not created with `new`, or the pointers are not *owned* by `A`, then `A`'s destructor should not delete them.

If `A` does own the pointers, it would be bad design, not to also allocate the objects within the class `A`. But I assume, that was left out of the example for simplicity.

As a sidenote: If `A` does own the pointers and deletes them in the destructor, then you should also implement the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator so that they make a deep copy or by making the class non-copyable. Otherwise you'll end up with undefined behaviour if you ever copy an instance.

> But as you see in Class B and Class C I go to class D, but there would be an error if I delete D?

Doing that is perfectly fine and there will be no error unless...

... if `A` owns the pointers to `B` and `C`, and `B` and `C` own the pointers to `D`, and `D` owns the pointers to `A`, so that they all delete the pointed objects, then there is an ownership cycle at class level. That's still fine unless...

... there is a cycle of pointers. For example, an instance of `D` (let's call it `dee`) points to an instance of `A` that points to an instance of `B` that points to `dee`, then you have a cycle and you end up deleting an object whose destructor has already started which results in undefined behaviour.

So, if such pointer cycle is possible, then the ownership cycle must be avoided. But if there can be no pointer cycle, then the ownership cycle may exist.

Comment: Yes it's just a simple example for the right way of thinking. But as you see in Class B and Class C I go to class D, but there would be an error if I delete D?

Comment: Tank you! I understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the constructor does.

In general terms, it is said that a constructor establishes a class invariant (a set of properties that all member functions can assume is true),  all member functions used externally to the class (e.g. public members, protected members that provide services to derived classes) maintain that invariant.  The destructor does the reverse of that the constructor does - for example, if the constructor explicitly allocates some resource, the destructor releases it.

If that invariant includes "all elements of `b` are assigned the result of operator `new`", then the destructor must release those elements using (the corresponding operator `delete`, or hand off to some other object that does so.    This is commonly described as ownership - class `A` takes actions that affect the lifetime of other objects, so must clean up.

If that invariant includes "all elements of `c` are either the NULL pointer, or contain the address of an object supplied from elsewhere" then the destructor should not release those objects.   For example, some other code may supply a pointer to a member function of `A`, and that pointer is simply placed into `c`.   This assumes you know that the lifetime of those objects is managed outside your class `A`.

Consider, for example, a constructor that does this

```
 A::A(int num_b, const std::vector<C *> &in_c) : b(0), c(in_c)
 {
     b.reserve(num_b);    // so b doesn't keep on resizing itself below
     for (int i = 0; i < num_b; ++i)
        b.push_back(new B);
 }
```

The logic of this is that `A` is allocating all the objects who's addresses are stored in `b`, but is simply copying pointers from `in_c` (which are presumably managed elsewhere).   So class `A` is responsible for the lifetime of the objects in `b`, but not those in `c`.

We then assume that, if member functions change `b` or `c` that the same still applies when `A`s destructor is invoked - all objects in `b` are managed by class `A`, but those in `c` are not.    (In other words, we assume the class invariant is maintained).

Then the destructor might look like

```
 A::~A()
 {
     for (std::vector<B *>::iterator i = b.begin(), end = b.end();
          i != end;
          ++i)
     {
          delete (*i);
     }
 }
```

Note that we don't need to resize `b` or `c`, since `std::vector`'s destructor takes care of cleaning itself up.   However, since our class allocated objects and stored their address in `b` - which `std::vector` has no knowledge of - the destructor must release them.

Note:  the above example works for all versions of C++.   Post C++11, the code in the destructor can be simplified, for example using new style loops or `auto` type deduction.